# Fatal error: Class 'Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials' not found

Tags: php, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to migrate the old google api to the new one, so I can get the google analytics data. I'm trying with [this](http://blog.anorgan.com/2015/01/15/using-google-analytics-api-with-php/) example, but it fires this error

> Fatal error: Class 'Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials' not found in
>   example.php

This is how I'm trying:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once 'google-api-php-client/vendor/autoload.php';
//$p12FilePath = '/path/to/key.p12';
$serviceClientId = '395545742105.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$serviceAccountName = '395545742105@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
$scopes = array(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'
);
$googleAssertionCredentials = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $serviceAccountName,
    $scopes
); // <- Fatal error here
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAssertionCredentials($googleAssertionCredentials);
$client->setClientId($serviceClientId);
$client->setApplicationName("Project");
$analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
```

And I did run a search for `Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials` in the library wich I download from [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/releases), and Just one result: upagrading.md

`Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials removed use Google_Client::setAuthConfig instead`,

But how should I use it in a contructor?

I tred

```
$googleAssertionCredentials = new Google_Client::setAuthConfig(
    $serviceAccountName,
    $scopes
);
```

With internal server error,

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: you might have better luck with Googles tutorial https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/web-php

Comment: I'm trying, but I can't find a way to download my client_secrets.json, I  tried to add manually the file with the syntax, but I'm getting `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Exception' with message 'Invalid client secret JSON file.' `

Comment: Client secrets json is found on the Google developers console.  check step 1 in the tutorial I linked

Comment: I know, I read, but there's not download json.. :S

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have a mixture of the old and new ([Google PHP API Client 2.0](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)) syntax. The message "use Google_Client::setAuthConfig instead" is meant to indicate the method to use, but not that it should be called statically.

It should look like this:

```
$client = new Google_Client();

// set the scope(s) that will be used
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'));

// this is needed only if you need to perform
// domain-wide admin actions, and this must be
// an admin account on the domain; it is not 
// necessary in your example but provided for others
$client->setSubject('youradmin@example.com');

// set the authorization configuration using the 2.0 style
$client->setAuthConfig(array(
    'type' => 'service_account',
    'client_email' => '395545742105@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
    'client_id' => '395545742105.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    'private_key' => 'yourkey'
));

$analyticsService = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
```

This syntax works for me with the current build as of this writing, which is `2.0.0-RC2`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a shot and let you know!

Answer (score 0):

This solution work for me:

The composer setup section in https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/README.md could mention both versions, something like:

composer require google/apiclient:^2.0.0@RC
Note the documentation at developers.google.com refers to V1 of this library. If you want to use the older version, instead use:
composer require google/apiclient:1.*

https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/748